# passing SDL windows by reference/address

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl, sdl-2

I don't want to use global variables for the SDL_Window and SDL_Renderer and any textures.

So i declared the window, renderer and texture at the top of main() and passed them to my init() function:

```
   bool init(SDL_Window* &window, SDL_Renderer* &renderer, const int height, const int width)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL_Init() failed SDL error: " << SDL_GetError() << '\n';
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, 0);
        if (window == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "SDL_CreateWindow() failed SDL error: " << SDL_GetError() << '\n';
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
            if (renderer == NULL)
            {
                std::cout << "SDL_CreateRenderer() failed SDL error: " << SDL_GetError() << '\n';
            }
        }
    }

    return true;

}
```

the caller in main():

```
if (!init(window, renderer, WINDOW_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH))
{
    std::cout << "init() failed SDL error: " << SDL_GetError() << '\n';
}
```

declarations at the top of main():

```
    SDL_Texture* texture{};
    SDL_Window* window{};
    SDL_Renderer* renderer{};
    int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 480;
    int WINDOW_WIDTH = 640;
```

as you can see in my init() function, it takes the window and renderer as arguments and puts them into one of these: SDL_Window* &window;
initially i tried putting them in : SDL_Window* window;
however this would result in the renderer and window being null when the program returned to main().

I don't understand why my initial method did not work but using SDL_Window* &window; does work

As far as i understand window is a pointer (a variable which holds an address) to a SDL struct called SDL_Window and therefore when i pass window to parameter SDL_Window* window, it should give the parameter the address to my window i declared in main() and therefore any changes made to the window in init() should also be made to it in main(), however this was not true and SDL_Window* &window as parameter ended up having the desired effect.

If possible could someone explain why this is?

Comment: You should read a good C book, since you seem to be struggling with the very basics of how pointers operate. *"when i pass window to parameter `SDL_Window*` window, it should give the parameter the address to my window i declared in `main()` and therefore any changes made to the window in `init()` should also be made to it in `main()`"* Firstly, you don't have any `SDL_Window` objects in `main`. You only have a pointer which doesn't point anywhere.

Comment: `init` doesn't change the object that the parameter could point to. It changes the pointer itself, by assigning the return value of `SDL_CreateWindow` to it. Thus even if the parameter pointed to an existing `SDL_Window` object, that object would be unaffected, since you reassign the pointer before using it in any other way. If you want changes made to the parameter (the pointer itself, not pointed object) to reflect on the argument you pass to your function, you have to pass by reference, or use an another level indirection by passing `SDL_Window **`.

Answer (score 1):

I think due do this being the first complex library I've used i became slightly confused about the nature of how and when objects were being created. Thanks to HolyBlackCat you made it obvious to me.

SDL_CreateWindow gives my window pointer an address which points to the created window, what i am passing in to init() is a default initialised pointer. for some reason i thought that declaring a pointer to an SDL_Window was also creating a space in memory for a window, its obvious due to the way that pointers work that this makes no sense